# Detecting iPad orientation in Delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

I'd have thought there would be an `OnRotate` event in XE4 but it appears that `OnResize` is used. Got that.

However, I need to determine which orientation the device is. I'm sure it's simple but Google can't help!

Comment: OnResize is no longer fired on orientation change. See new solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670119/delphi-android-detect-device-orientation-change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To detect the current orientation of the device you can use the `statusBarOrientation` method  which is part of the [`UIApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Try this sample

```
uses
  iOSapi.UIKit;

function SharedApplication:UIApplication;
begin
  Result:=TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
end;

procedure TForm23.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LOrientation: Cardinal;
begin
  LOrientation := SharedApplication.statusBarOrientation;
  if (LOrientation = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) or (LOrientation = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) then
    ShowMessage('Landscape')
  else
  if (LOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) then
    ShowMessage('Portrait');
end;
```

Comment: Tried this with Portrait and inverted portrait, if you call the code on the Onresize, it goes like this: portrait - detected, inverted portrait - detected, then it stops detecting any changes. Maybe I am doing something wrong... will post if I find out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that checking the hieght and width is the way. If h > w then potrait, else landscape.  Surprised there isn't something built in though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my function on OnResize event of the main form.

> function TERMainForm.GetOrientation: TScreenOrientation; 
>   var
>   OrientationS: IFMXScreenService; 
>   begin
>   if
>   TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService,
>     IInterface(OrientationS)) then
>   begin
>       Result := OrientationS.GetScreenOrientation;
>   end
>   else
>    raise Exception.Create('Orientation not supported'); 
>   end;