# Firemonkey Delphi device specific orientations

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am looking for a way to specify how to ensure a phone app only displays in portrait mode, a tablet in landscape (possibly portrait too) and windows tablet/pc in landscape only.

I have found how to set this in the project/options but this is to set the OS to specific modes, not the actual devices regardless of which OS is used. ie: all Apple and Android phones would be in portrait mode, not just all android devices or all iOS devices.

Preferably I would add it code, but if anyone can assist it would much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670119

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCshVa6rEr8">IFMXScreenService FireMonkey

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for.  I don't want to detect the screen orientation and pixel size.  It is the device type that I'm after detecting. ie: all iphones/android and windows phone will be set to portrait.  ipad/android/windows tablest 10in or above will work in both landscape and portrait modes, while tablets at 7in/8in would only work in landscape mode.  I've looked around on line and I don't think it is actually possible.  You can detect pixels and guess the device from there, but obviously that is far from perfect.  thanks anyway.

Comment: If the reason for allowing landscape is related to screen size, why not just detect screen size, rather than attempting to determine whether or not a device is a phone or tablet?